# AdMob: Invalid frame size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, admob

I am trying to implement ads in my app, code and app running perfectly, but ads not.
I am getting an error in console

```
<Google> Invalid Request. Invalid ad width or height: (0, 0)
bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: Invalid ad width or height: (0, 0)
```

Even if I Add frame width and height. Here is my simple code for test:

```
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                BannerAd(unitID:
                            "ca-app-pub ...")
                .frame(width: 320, height: 50)
            }
```

I tried adding frame, changing width and height but still getting this error.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. I just had BannerAd without anything.
If anyone are struggling with this try to do that under the text:

```
VStack { 
  Text("") 
  BannerAd(unitID:"ca-app-pub ...")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had my BannerAd(unitID:"ca-app-pub ...") inside a ScrollView. When I moved it to a ZStack, it worked.